# Replace "C:\fakepath\" to "\\server\folder\"

Tags: javascript

I use javascript code to take the file path and paste it into the text input. I am wondering how to make it substitute a predefined server path in front of the file name instead of the path "C:\fakepath", e.g: "\server\dir\data".

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').val( $(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" onchange="this.form.filename.value = this.value">
  <input type="text" name="filename">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String object has a number of methods that you could use for this. For example using substr:

```
<script>
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').val( '\\server\\dir\\data'+$(this).val().substr(11));
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript from knowing your file's local full path and because of which you are getting fakepath in the file path url. This security feature is added so that the server won't able to know the filesystem of your machine.
In case you you want to remove the fakepath from path then what you can do is to -

```
$('input[type="text"]').val( '\'+$(this).val());
```

This will show the the path as **\file_name.extension**

Answer (score -1):

- of what you wrote i guess that you are trying to do file upload by sending the file data from files object to the server by ajax but you cannot send this path or replace it because it's a random path generated when the server received the file to be uploaded but you can easily use `FormData` object to send the file to the server then you can handle it from your server

> Here's an example

```
var photo = document.getElementById("photo")
photo.addEventListener("change",function(event) {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file",event.target.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: './phpScripts/up.php',
        type: "post",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: form_data
    }).done(function(e) {
        //Code here
    })
})
```

- the last point if you wants to get the file path just test the event in the console `console.log(event)` then search for files object when you can find the file path and access it